# How to create hash of hash key

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $s = "12   A    P1  
23   B    P5
24   C    P2
15   D    P1
06   E    P5 ";
my $hash = {};
my @a  = split(/\n/, $s);

foreach (@a)
{
  my $c = (split)[2];
  my $d = (split)[1];
  my $e = (split)[0];
  push(@{$hash->{$c}}, $d);
}
print Dumper($hash );
```

I am getting the output

```
    $VAR1 = {
   'P5' => [
             'B',
             'E'
           ],
   'P2' => [
             'C'
           ],
   'P1' => [
             'A',
             'D'
           ]
    };
```

But I want the output like

```
 $VAR1 = {
'P5' => {
 'E' => '06',
 'B' => '23'
  },
 'P2' => {
   'C' => '24'
 },
 'P1' => {
   'A' => '12',
   'D' => '15'
 }
  };
```

Please help.

Comment: This is a follow-up to previous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613452/how-to-create-hash-with-duplicate-keys

Comment: Nitech, please be aware that you can only accept one answer.

Comment: @daxim: yes it is the follow up. actually from last 2 hours i was trying this and didnt get. i got almost frustated. I modified my last question and nobody replied. thats why i raised a fresh query.

Comment: @Nitesh Be aware that if you have multiple keys they will be overwritten with this approach. E.g. `"12  A  P1"` and `"43  A  P1"` will share the same hash key, and earlier values will be overwritten by later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a hash if you want a hash as output.

No need to split three times and use postscripts, just split once and assign all variables. Also no need to initialize a scalar as an empty hash, perl will take care of that for you.

I renamed the variables for increased readability.

```
my $string = "12   A    P1  
23   B    P5
24   C    P2
15   D    P1
06   E    P5 ";
my $hash;
my @lines = split(/\n/, $string);

foreach (@lines)
{
    my ($value, $key2, $key) = split;
    $hash->{$key}{$key2} = $value;
}
print Dumper($hash );
```

Be aware that if you have multiple values with the same keys, they will overwrite each other. In that case, you'd need to push the values onto an array instead:

```
push @{$hash->{$key}{$key2}}, $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not that different from what you have. Just replace the `push` with a hash-assign (thank you auto-vivification):

```
foreach (@a)
{
    my ($e, $d, $c) = split;
    $hash->{$c}->{$d} = $e;
}
```

Additionally I have re-arranged the "split" so that it's just called once per line.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Its working. But i didnt get ho its working. Coz there are duplicate keys.